# Return an array of True/False based on two columns meeting a criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I would like to adjust the following CSE formula to return an array of Booleans for each row should the criteria in columns A and B be met. The statement below is acting as an OR function currently.

```
= (A:A="Y")+(B:B="Y")
```

E.g.if I have two columns as follows I'd like a third column C with the formula to return as follows:

```
A   B   C
Y   N   {False,False,True}
N   Y   {False,False,True}
Y   Y   {False,False,True}
```

The formula above currently returns:

```
A   B   C

Y   N   {True,True,True}

N   Y   {True,True,True}

Y   Y   {True,True,True}
```

Comment: Change the `+` to `*`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `TRANSPOSE()` function: `=TRANSPOSE(((A:A="Y")+(B:B="Y"))=2)`

The CSE formula `=(A:A="Y")+(B:B="Y")` will return a tall array: `{FALSE;FALSE;TRUE}`. `{FALSE,FALSE,TRUE}` is a long array. `TRANSPOSE` will convert tall to long and vice-versa.